# gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3> django

Tags: python, django, gunicorn

I have a django app and trying to set it up with gunicorn first and later with supervisor and nginx.

The app is running with the normal django command perfectly like `python manage.py runserver`

I installed the gunicorn using pip like `pip install gunicorn` and django version is `1.5.3`

when i run the below command inside the virtual env like below

`gunicorn  hello.wsgi:application -b xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8000` and faced the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/Envs/proj/bin/gunicorn", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('gunicorn==19.0.0', 'console_scripts', 'gunicorn')()
  File "/root/Envs/proj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 74, in run
    WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()
  File "/root/Envs/proj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 166, in run
    super(Application, self).run()
  File "/root/Envs/proj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 71, in run
    Arbiter(self).run()
  File "/root/Envs/proj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 169, in run
    self.manage_workers()
  File "/root/Envs/proj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 477, in manage_workers
    self.spawn_workers()
  File "/root/Envs/proj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 537, in spawn_workers
    time.sleep(0.1 * random.random())
  File "/root/Envs/proj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 209, in handle_chld
    self.reap_workers()
  File "/root/Envs/proj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 459, in reap_workers
    raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
```

So why actually the above error is encountered and whats the fix ?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Actually the problem here was the wsgi file itself, previously before django 1.3 the wsgi file was named with an extension  of `.wsgi`, but now in the recent versions it will be created with and extension of `.py` that is the wsgi file must be a python module

so the file should be `hello_wsgi.py` and command should be

```
gunicorn  hello:application -b xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8000
```

Comment: I had a similar issue and I had a better idea of what was the problem by running `gunicorn --log-file=-`, this will output log straight in the console. http://stackoverflow.com/a/25689349/1092815

Comment: I recommend seeing a below answer about using the --preload arg: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55623889/3559330

Answer (score 91):

run guncorn with --preload can see the error log, like this

```
gunicorn app:application --preload -b 0.0.0.0:5000
```

This will usually give you a more detailed error message.

Comment: shall we write this command exactly as it is? or shall I replace app OR application with another value? if it should be replaced, how to get the value to be put here?

Comment: I just added --preload to my command line and it showed me the problem.

Answer (score 15):

You didn't show a full output. It probably looks like

```
$ gunicorn elcarweb.wsgi
[2015-10-27 21:01:47 +0000] [5429] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.2.1
[2015-10-27 21:01:47 +0000] [5429] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (5429)
[2015-10-27 21:01:47 +0000] [5429] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2015-10-27 21:01:47 +0000] [5434] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 5434
[2015-10-27 21:01:47 +0000] [5434] [ERROR] Exception in worker process:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tomek/Elcar/elcarweb/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 503, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/home/tomek/Elcar/elcarweb/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 116, in init_process
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/home/tomek/Elcar/elcarweb/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/home/tomek/Elcar/elcarweb/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/home/tomek/Elcar/elcarweb/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/home/tomek/Elcar/elcarweb/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 355, in import_app
    __import__(module)
ImportError: No module named elcarweb.wsgi
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tomek/Elcar/elcarweb/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 503, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/home/tomek/Elcar/elcarweb/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 116, in init_process
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/home/tomek/Elcar/elcarweb/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/home/tomek/Elcar/elcarweb/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/home/tomek/Elcar/elcarweb/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/home/tomek/Elcar/elcarweb/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 355, in import_app
    __import__(module)
ImportError: No module named elcarweb.wsgi
[2015-10-27 21:01:47 +0000] [5434] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 5434)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tomek/Elcar/elcarweb/env/bin/gunicorn", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(run())
  File "/home/tomek/Elcar/elcarweb/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 74, in run
    WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()
  File "/home/tomek/Elcar/elcarweb/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 189, in run
    super(Application, self).run()
  File "/home/tomek/Elcar/elcarweb/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 72, in run
    Arbiter(self).run()
  File "/home/tomek/Elcar/elcarweb/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 170, in run
    self.manage_workers()
  File "/home/tomek/Elcar/elcarweb/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 473, in manage_workers
    self.spawn_workers()
  File "/home/tomek/Elcar/elcarweb/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 537, in spawn_workers
    time.sleep(0.1 * random.random())
  File "/home/tomek/Elcar/elcarweb/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 210, in handle_chld
    self.reap_workers()
  File "/home/tomek/Elcar/elcarweb/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 455, in reap_workers
    raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
```

Last trackback is almost the same, but before You see required informations:

```
ImportError: No module named elcarweb.wsgi
```

If You see this error, then solution is run gunicorn with `--chdir=/your/app/dir` parameter.

Comment: i.e. in your gunicorn `exec` command within **gunicorn.conf**, add `--chdir==/home/user/dir` (`dir` being the directory containing your django project).

Comment: Adding this argument didn't cut it for me, I had to `cd` to this directory first otherwise `gunicorn` had no way of finding my project.

Comment: For me in Ubuntu 22.04 worked `--chdir /home/username/projectdir`

Answer (score 12):

For anyone facing the same issue, the problem is usually something in django itself.
Activate your venv and run ./manage.py runserver

This will usually give you a more detailed error message.

Comment: Also you can run any command such as djangi-admin runserver or django-admin migrate

Answer (score 4):

I also had a similar error in Ubuntu 16.04, Django 1.11, using systemd.

My problem was that I had split my settings out into separate files; ie: instead of having all settings in project/settings.py, I have a few settings files like project/settings/dev.py.

I had to update DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE in the project/wsgi.py file from:

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "project.settings")
```

to

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "project.settings.dev")
```

then gunicorn worked.

Comment: I really can't believe this worked! Sounds so easy but the amount of answers and tuts I had to go through to find this gem. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 2):

I got the very same error.
[Gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org/) was working when executed as root, but failed this way when executed as non-privileged user.
In my case I install the 'dataset' python module with 'pip install dataset' and it screwed the permissions on `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dataset` to be readable only by root account. On other module installed as dependency like that was normality.

Fix :

```
chmod -R a+rX /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dataset*
chmod -R a+rX /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/normality*
```

Some another issue was with the yaml package auto-installed by pip, but I have not found what exactly. The fix was to reinstall from fedora package:

```
dnf -y install python-yaml
```