# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'onbytes'

Tags: django, python-3.x, gunicorn

I have a Django app that I created and am trying to deploy onto Google Cloud Platform. When I try to go to the given link after running `gcloud app deploy`, I get a `502 Bad Gateway` error. Looking at the logs, I see this error:

```
gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
```

I looked this up and from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24639907/gunicorn-errors-haltserver-haltserver-worker-failed-to-boot-3) stackoverflow post, I tried running the following command locally:

```
gunicorn --log-file=- onbytes.wsgi:application
```

However, I get the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'onbytes'
```

Nothing comes up when I look this up on google. I tried running `pip3 install onbytes` but that failed to yield anything. Anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was another error message in the log slightly above the one I was looking at:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'corsheaders'
```

I got it to work after installing `corsheaders` through the command:

```
pip install django-cors-headers
```

and then adding it to the `requirements.txt`

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Old question though.
But, it seems the mistake was specifying onbytes instead of your project name.
Like this.

```
gunicorn --log-file=- yourprojectname.wsgi:application
```

This is because, by default, the wsgi.py file is under the folder with your project name and application is a variable set in that file - mostly like:

```
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'yourprojectname.settings')
application = get_wsgi_application()
```